# Unity 2D Continuous Jumping

Tags: unity-game-engine, move

Friends I am working on a game. I want to keep moving the character in equal intervals continuously. But I can not do this. I jump continuously in the jump of the jump in the physical material and at the same time I force the character to 1e -1 with the AdForce method. the speed is increasing and it is getting higher. I want both the speed to be fixed and the height to be constant. I am waiting for your emergency help in this regard. Thank you in advance!

Comment: *`I jump continuously in the jump of the jump`* ...What?

Comment: C'mon Draco, this is elementary, he jump continuosly in the jump of the jump. What don't you understand about that? In all seriousness though, we have no idea what you're trying to ask us. Please check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

To provide a good answer I need more information about your game, is this a 2d platformer or a fighting game? Please provide a little more info. That being said I think the reason your speed is always increasing is because you are using addForce. Try something like this instead

```
rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal,vertical);
```

The reason is because addForce will add a speed increase to the speed your character had in the last update call